# Hidden Windows shortcuts

Tags: windows, shortcut

Anyone know where I can find a list of the different hidden shortcuts built into windows like "control userpasswords2".

I'm building a small app that will help my team get to those buried panels such as the pagefile settings, IE's proxy settings, Editing the Boot.ini

***I am not talking about shortcut keys like ctrl+alt+del. But commands you can put into the run dialog.
Thank you

To elaborate more, I'm looking for a list like [MS KB192806](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192806) & [commands](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/control.htm), & [another](http://www.wilsonmar.com/1mmcs.htm).  That gives me some of the commands I'm looking for like "control intl.cpl".  However I'm looking for others that are not in that list and I would like more control. For example to go strait to the connections tab when running "control intl.cpl".

Comment: My keyboard does not have a userpasswords2 key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find control panel specific list here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192806

For your application, I would recommend you to design the required interfaces and take the input from user directly in to your application. After that, you can make the user defined changes from your program. Most (not all) of these settings are stored in registry which you can modify appropriately. Its easy to find the required registry key by searching on net or using some monitoring tools (like regmon or procmon).

Also note that, just setting the registry values will not always update the configuration immediately. Some setting changes have to be notified to the respective programs.

There are few similar software already available on the net, which can do management of few basic stuffs.

Comment: Thanks, that will definitely help.   But I know theres a longer list out there somewhere.